# graphql запрос в классовых компонентах react apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

каким образом можно запрашивать данные с сервера при помощи graphql и apollo, если я пишу на классовых компонентах (по определенным причинам я не могу использовать функциональные компоненты)?

Answer (score 0):

[ответ тут][1]

[1]: https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/react/apollo-client-without-hooks/. Можно использовать экземпляр ApolloClient, у него есть метод query